# angularjs get form action and submit to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form and I want to catch it submission, check validation of data and than submit form to the action inside the HTML form.

```
<div ng-controller="contactCtrl">
   <form action="someAction" method="post" name="contactForm" class="clearfix frmContact">
      <div class="one_half">
         <input id="txtName" ng-model="name" value="" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <button ng_click="save($event)" type="submit">Send Message</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

and my js:

```
var app = angular.module('bloompyApp', []);

app.controller("contactCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.email = "";
    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.left  = function() {return 100 - $scope.message.length;};
    $scope.clear = function() {$scope.message = "";};
    $scope.save  = function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        console.log(angular.element(document.querySelector('body')));

        if ($scope.contactForm.$valid) {
            $http.get("/posts/")
                .success(function(response) {console.log(response);});
        }


    };
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You should:

1. Use the [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) directive on your form
2. Pass the form element to your `save()` method
3. Use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service to post

```js
var ctrl = function ($scope, $http, $log) {
$scope.save = function (form) {
    //if (!$scope.contactForm.$valid) return;
    
    var url = form.attributes["target"];
    $log.debug(url);
  
    $http
      .post(url, { email: $scope.email, name: $scope.name })
      .success(function (response) {
        $log.debug(response);
      })
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form ng-submit="save($element.action)">

    <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: yes that is good, but as you can see, the js code decides the action, I want the action to be taken from the html form action

Comment: Thanks Zach, exactly what I needed. @Tzook if you must have the action in the view then throw it in a data attribute and fetch it in the js for use.

Answer (score 0):

I really advice you to follow this page of the docs from the beginning to the end, you'll change your approach to form using AngularJS :)

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) instead on the form element

"Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), but only if the form does not contain action, data-action, or x-action attributes."

It will also only run the expressions **if the native html5 validation** is valid