# How can I use Form Action in the latest version of Ionic Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am creating Form action using ionic-v2 and Angular-2.It gives me error, please suggest me how can I use Form action.

my ionic 2 Html code

```
<form (ngSubmit)="logForm()" action="" method="post"></form>
```

Comment: Can you please have a look at this quetion. https://stackoverflow.com/q/25953541/7812329

Comment: what error you are getting..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs get form action and submit to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953541/angularjs-get-form-action-and-submit-to-it)

Comment: I am not getting any error but form action does not pass the data to server....

Comment: I am using angular-2 and ionic 2,form action is not working...

Comment: Did you ever get this working?